# Thresholds on integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, comparison, coordinates, threshold

I need to set thresholds on an x,y coords so that i can analyse numbers surrounding those coordinates. basically i need set a low threshold 1 below x and 1 below y and set a high threshold of 1 above x and 1 above y.

I also have limits so that if either x or y is 0 the low threshold is 0 and if x or y is 9 the high threshold is 9

The code i have so far is as follows: - its the same for y so i only posted finding thresholds for x...

```
bool CheckNextTo(int X, int Y){
        int LowThreshX,LowthreshY;
        int HighThreshX,HighThreshY;

        if (X == 0){
            LowThreshX =0;
            HighThreshX =X+1;
        }
        else if (X== 9){
            LowThreshX =X-1;
            HighThreshX=9;
        }
        else{
            LowThreshX=X-1;
            HighThreshX=X+1;
        }
}
```

This works i'm just wandering if there is an easier way to do this as i will have to write all this again to work out Y thresholds. I know i could write function that returns thresholds too but besides that is there anything else?

Thanks

Comment: Google clamping as this is the concept you are looking for

Comment: could i possibly have some example code? i looked it up but im q bit confused on how it assigns either 1 up or 1 down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Min` and `Max` functions come in handy:

```
LowThresholdX= Max(0, X-1);
HighThresholdX= Min(9, X+1);
LowThresholdY= Max(0, Y-1);
HighThresholdY= Min(9, Y+1);
```

Comment: Compared to an *if then else if* solution, there is a tiny loss of efficiency because a single comparison suffices when `X<=0` (resp. `Y<=0`). In the case at hand processing all `X` values in range `[0..9]` takes `20` comparisons instead of... `19`.

Comment: Math::Max is not a C++ function. Use max() macro or std::max in the algorithms library. See my (correct) answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary if operator, which is built-in in many languages (C and C++ included)

> (condition ? then : else)

```
LowThresholdX= (X == 0 ? 0 : X-1);
HighThresholdX= (X == 9 ? 9 : X+1);
LowThresholdY= (Y == 0 ? 0 : Y-1);
HighThresholdY= (Y == 9 ? 9 : Y+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really understood what you want but writing things without repetition might make things clearer to you.

Your code becomes :

```
bool CheckNextTo(int X, int Y){
        int LowThreshX = X-1;
        int HighThreshX = X+1;

        if (X == 0){
            LowThreshX = 0;
        }
        else if (X == 9){
            HighThreshX = 9;
        }
}
```

which might as well be written :

```
bool CheckNextTo(int X, int Y){
        int LowThreshX = X-1;
        int HighThreshX = X+1;

        if (X == MIN){
            LowThreshX = X;
        }
        else if (X == MAX){
            HighThreshX = X;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool CheckNextTo(int X, int Y){
  int LowThreshX = MAX(0,X-1);
  int LowThreshY = MAX(0,Y-1);
  int HighThreshX = MIN(9,X+1);
  int HighThreshX = MIN(9,Y+1);
}
```

MAX, MIN are either the macro functions or std::max/min.

You could write this as a function, but that would depend on how your other code works, and you haven't shown us that.

Comment: i believe the answer already accepted (by @Yves Daoust) is the same as this one.

Comment: I don't think so. Math::Max/Min is not C++. But I agree it's close -- his answer was not submitted when I wrote mine.

Comment: What's the point ? stl is not C++ either and there are no predefined MIN/MAX macros.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: STL? In MSVC the macros min/max are defined in minmax.h. Template functions std::min/max are defined in algorithm. Use whichever you prefer.

Comment: Yep, none of the standard template library (std namespace), the Windows API and the .NET API (Math namespace among others) are in the C++ standard.

Comment: See n3337 S25.4.7. And every C/C++ compiler I have ever used (quite a few) has a macro implementation of min/max similar to the example given at N3337 S16.3.5/4. Both these are highly portable, where the Math namespace is not.